# TryRuby raises undefined method `[]=' for String

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I am working to replace a character in a string, changing `"cat"` into `"hat"`.

Here's my code:

```
str = "cat"
str[0] = 'h'
puts str
```

But when I run this code in [TryRuby](https://ruby.github.io/TryRuby/) I get this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for "cat"

Comment: This code works fine (ruby 2.5.1 and 1.8.7 [link](https://eval.in/1027775))

Comment: l am using Try ruby's editor (https://ruby.github.io/TryRuby/). It seems like it's ruby version's problem( Sorry for posting an awkward question)  Trying to find out the version Try Ruby uses, but haven't have any luck yet

Comment: It claims to be using 2.1.1, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is sandboxed/restricted. It works in real 2.1.1. For best results, install a local ruby copy.

Comment: Try Ruby use 2.1.1 but it seems that they undefined `String#[]=` for some reason.

Comment: @dark.o _"Sorry for posting an awkward question"_ – your question isn't awkward, your Ruby version is ;-)

Comment: I am perplexed why you awarded the greenie to a non-answer. You asked why you got a particular error when using TryRuby, not how the substitution could be done differently. Please reconsider your selection. Judging from the voting I do not think I'm alone in that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) method and do it like this:

```
str = 'cat'

puts str.gsub(str[0], 'h')
```

Comment: this would be an issue for say `"catch"`. In this case you could use `String#sub` instead of `String#gsub` but that too would have issues if you were going for `str[3] = "h"`

Answer (score 6):

> l am using Try ruby's editor

[ruby.github.io/TryRuby](https://ruby.github.io/TryRuby/) uses [Opal](http://opalrb.com/) (a Ruby-to-JavaScript compiler) to evaluate the code in the browser. Opal provides its own [`String`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/string.rb) class which doesn't implement `[]=`.

This seems to be a known limitation (among others). From the [documentation](http://opalrb.com/docs/guides/v0.11.0/unsupported_features.html): (emphasis added)

> For performance and ease of runtime features, **all strings in Opal are immutable**, i.e. #<<, #gsub!, etc. do not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: Nice research. That is one brutal limitation especially for a site called "Try[Something Kind of Like]Ruby"

Comment: @engineersmnky IIRC, _why's original version and its first (or so) successor was evaluated server-side using an actual Ruby interpreter (probably running in safe mode or sandboxed in some way).